# C++ binary files I/O, data lost when writing

Tags: c++, char, integer, ifstream, ofstream

I am learning C++ with the "Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++" book from Bjarne Stroustrup. I am currently studying chapter 11 and I found an example on how to **read and write binary files of integers** (section 11.3.2). I played around with the example and used a .txt file (input.txt) with a sentence which I read and wrote to another file (output.txt) (text_to_binary fnc) and then read and wrote back to the original file (input.txt) (binary_to_text fnc).

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void text_to_binary(ifstream &ifs, ofstream &ofs)
{
    for (int x; ifs.read(as_bytes(x), sizeof(char));)
    {
        ofs << x << '\n';
    }
    ofs.close();
    ifs.close();
}

void binary_to_text(ifstream &ifs, ofstream &ofs)
{
    for (int x; ifs >> x;)
    {
        ofs.write(as_bytes(x), sizeof(char));
    }
    ifs.close();
    ofs.close();
}

int main()
{
    string iname = "./chapter_11/input.txt";
    string oname = "./chapter_11/output.txt";

    ifstream ifs{iname, ios_base::binary};
    ofstream ofs{oname, ios_base::binary};

    text_to_binary(ifs, ofs);

    ifstream ifs2{oname, ios_base::binary};
    ofstream ofs2{iname, ios_base::binary};

    binary_to_text(ifs2, ofs2);

    return 0;
}
```

I figured out that I have to use sizeof(**char**) rather than sizeof(**int**) in the .read and .write command. If I use the sizeof(int) some chars of the .txt file go missing when I write them back to text. Funnily enough chars only goes missing if

> x%4 != 0 (x = nb of chars in .txt file)

example with sizeof(int):

input.txt:
`hello this is an amazing test. 1234 is a number everything else doesn't matter..asd`

(text_to_binary fnc) results in:

output.txt:

```
1819043176
1752440943
1763734377
1851859059
1634558240
1735289210
1936028704
824192628
540291890
1629516649
1836412448
544367970
1919252069
1768453241
1696622446
543519596
1936027492
544483182
1953784173
774795877
```

(binary_to_text fnc) results back in:

input.txt:
`hello this is an amazing test. 1234 is a number everything else doesn't matter..`
**asd** went missing.

Now to my question, why does this happen? Is it because int's are saved as 4 bytes?

Bonus question: Out of interest, is there a simpler/more efficient way of doing this?

edit: updated the question with the results to make it hopefully more clear

Comment: Does that code even build? It can't be using [`std::as_bytes`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/as_bytes). Using non-standard headers like your `"../std_lib_facilities.h"` doesn't help to make your code easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: As for your problem, `sizeof(char)` is specified to *always* be `1`. And that means you're only read and write a single byte of your (probably) four-byte integer.

Comment: Looks like the code is reading binary integers of 1 byte, and writing those values as decimal strings, one per line.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah the code builds fine. the header file includes the namespace std. let me change the post to make it more clear.
yeah I think I udnerstand that, but if I use sizeof(int) on some text. some of the text goes missing.

Comment: Off-topic tip: Close the streams in the same scope as they were created in, instead of inside the functions. For a small example it makes no difference, but for larger projects this can make the flow more obvious and can help avoiding wrong assumptions.

Comment: @olm cool thanks for the tip. i was wondering where i should put the .close().

Comment: Try adding another character, so instead of `asd` you have `asdf`. And check the size of the input file. Is it a multiple of `sizeof(int)` or not?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude if i add another char then nothing is missing. 
since i have 84 characters and 84%4 = 0. which leads to my question in the first place, why do characters only go missing when the nb of characters%4 !=0?
is it because sizeof(int) only "accepts" multiples of 4 (since a int is 4 bytes)?

Comment: When you use `sizeof(int)` then it must be a multiple of that size. You can't do partial reads or writes.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ok, that basically answers my question. thank you very much! Is there a way I can accept your comment as answer?

Comment: @wuschelbueb No, but I can edit my existing (but deleted) answer to say only this. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you attempt to do a partial read, the read will attempt to go beyond the end of the file and the `eof` flag will be set for the stream. This makes its use in the loop condition `false` so the loop ends.

You need to check [`gcount`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/gcount) of the stream *after* the loop to see if any bytes was actually read into the variable `x`.

***But*** note that partial reads will only write to parts of the variable `x`, leaving the rest *indeterminate*. Exactly which parts depends on the system [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), and using the variable with its indeterminate bits will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: I updated the post, I think I wasn't clear enough sorry about that. What i am wondering is, why do i lose some letters when I use sizeof(int) instead of sizeof(chars).
I was just testing your suggestion and changed the x to a char. If I do that I lose all the whitespaces when i transform the output.txt back.